# MVC jqgrid - cannot get Model Binding to work to edit object for cell update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

I am using JQGrid to edit a grid of data.
I want to send the data in the cell to be edited on the server.
So my view looks like;

```
@using Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid
@using Tac.P3.Model
@model ContractType

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Contract Types";
    var grid = new JqGridHelper<ContractType>(
        "ContractTypes",
        dataType: JqGridDataTypes.Json,
        methodType: JqGridMethodTypes.Post,
        pager: true,
        rowsNumbers: true,
        rowsNumber: 20,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        cellEditingEnabled: true,
        cellEditingSubmitMode: JqGridCellEditingSubmitModes.Remote,
        cellEditingUrl:Url.Action("Update", "ContractType"),
        sortingName: "ContractTypeLabel", sortingOrder: JqGridSortingOrders.Asc,
        url: Url.Action("GridData"),
        viewRecords: true)
        .Navigator(new JqGridNavigatorOptions()
                       {
                           Add = false,
                           Edit = false,
                           Delete = false,
                           Search = false
                       });
}

<div class="mainPage">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add New Contract Type</legend>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="@Url.Action("Add")">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-1">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContractTypeLabel)</div>
                <div class="col-xs-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContractTypeLabel)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-1">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)</div>
                <div class="col-xs-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmitForm">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>List of Contract Types</legend>
        @Html.Partial("_Messages")
        <div id="loadingMessage" class="errorHighlight">Loading list of Contract Types, please wait...</div>
        @grid.GetHtml()
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

My method on the controller looks like

```
public ActionResult Update(CellEditingViewModel viewModel)
{
    var contractType = this.TacUoW.ContractType.GetById(viewModel.Id);
    switch (viewModel.PropertyName)
    {
        case "ContractTypeLabel":
            contractType.ContractTypeLabel = viewModel.PropertyValue.ToString();
            break;

        case "Description":
            contractType.Description = viewModel.PropertyValue.ToString();
            break;
    }

    this.TacUoW.ContractType.Update(contractType);
    this.TacUoW.SaveChanges();
    return this.Json(true);
}
```

My view model looks like;

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(CellEditingViewModelBinder))]
public class CellEditingViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public object PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

My ModelBinder looks like;

```
public class CellEditingViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var model = new CellEditingViewModel { Id = Convert.ToInt32(request.Params["ContractTypeId"]) };

        if (request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("ContractTypeLabel"))
        {
            model.PropertyName = "ContractTypeLabel";
            model.PropertyValue = request.Params["ContractTypeLabel"];
        }
        else if (request.Params.AllKeys.Contains("Description"))
        {
            model.PropertyName = "Description";
            model.PropertyValue = request.Params["Description"];                
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

When I press transmitt in the grid, I get an empty object sent to the controller method, no model binding takes place. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You wrote the question as pure [Lib.Web.Mvc](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc) problem and not jqGrid problem. Do you examined [the examples](https://tpeczek.codeplex.com/)? I added at least [lib.web.mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lib.web.mvc/info) tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks for doing that Oleg. The CRUD example does not use cell editing. I do not think I will find it in any other example on that page.

Comment: It's the problem if you use a product which knows not so much people and for which you don't have enough of examples. I hope that [tpeczek](https://github.com/tpeczek) will see your question and will write his answer or at least his comment. If you will not get solution I would recommend you to open JavaScript code in web browser which was generated by `Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid`. In the way you will provide **jqGrid** code. One can add some additional JavaScript code to it to do what you need. One can trace HTTP traffic to examine where client send editing data to the server and which one.

Comment: So one can examine the problem as **jqGrid** probem, but I can't help you if you post only C# code which uses `Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid`. It can be that your problem exist just because you expect `ContractTypeId` or `Id` in input data of editing and you have `id` instead (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server)). One can use `prmNames` parameter of jqGrid (`prmNames: {id: "ContractTypeId"}`), but I can't gives you direct advice in case of usage `Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid`.

Comment: Probably `parametersNames: new JqGridParametersNames { Id = "ContractTypeId" }` will help you. Like [here](https://tpeczek.codeplex.com/discussions/435518).

Comment: Ah yes, I look at the jqGrid code and I notice that the cellEditingSubmitMode does not get translated. I suspect that might be a bug in Lib.Web.Mvc, or more likely I am not using it properly.

Comment: You can exectute `$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {/*any jqGrid option of callback*/});` code **before** the grid will be created (for example) directly after jqGrid JavaScript will be inserted (no document ready are required). In the way you can include `prmNames` or `cellEdit: true` or any other option or callback. So if `Lib.Web.Mvc` do the main job with binding the data and generating `colModel` you can do all other things in JavaScript.

Comment: What I tried did not work, maybe I misunderstood? I put this in my code;     <script type="text/javascript">
        $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, { cellSubmit: 'remote' });
        $(function () {
            @grid.GetJavaScript();
            $('#loadingMessage').hide();
        });
    </script>

Comment: If the code `<script type="text/javascript">$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, { cellEdit: true, cellSubmit: 'remote' });</script>` after `grid.locale-en.js` then all jqGrids which you creates will have the options and cell editing will work. In the same way you can make more option as **default** options of jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was, and I have not posted all the code to show it.
For my class CellEditingViewModel I was using

```
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
```

Which is wrong. I should have been using

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```